# For TLS AES_CCM mode how does CBC_MAC work when the message length is not aligned to block size?

Tags: aes, tls, padding, cbc-mac, ccm

Even after goign through lot of specs I failed to understand how CBC-MAC works, specifically in case we have message not aligned to 16 bytes. Are there any padding bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [RFC 3610](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3610), 2.2 *Authentication* (page 3):

> The message blocks are formed by splitting the message $m$ into 16-octet blocks, and then padding the last block with zeroes if necessary.